# Data Queries Sporadically Return Empty Recordsets

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I am using ado with asp.net. I am using some stored procedure to get records from database. While working in a single tab it works all fine, but if i open same page in next tab then the previous tab gives an error while the page in new tab works fine. I get the following error which is caused due to empty record sets.

> ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'
>
> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record."

Not sure what is going on. Is the problem in database access or ADO connection?

Comment: Where is your sp code?

Comment: The sp is just a simple "SELECT" query. don't think there is any problem with it

Comment: Please post your (relevant) code and the query. It sounds like the there is no data in your result.